# Azure Load balancer static IPs

Tags: azure, dns, azure-active-directory, static-ip-address

Are Azure public IPs truly static or can they change?

I have 2 load balancers each have 2 VMs behind them.
I offer a multi-tenant SAAS solution to my end users and ask that they map a CNAME record in their DNS to our domain name. www.ourDomain.com

There are some scenarios where i would allow the end user to map an A record to our IPs. How risky is this with Azure IPs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, whatever basic or standard load balancer you are using, both are supporting to assign the public-facing load balancing solution with the **static** allocation method.

For basic SKU LB, you can change the basic public IP from the dynamic allocation method to static, for standard SKU LB, Azure always uses static allocation method for your standard public IP.

So there is no risk unless you are assigning the public IP to other resources or release these public IPs. For more details, you can look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-ip-addresses-overview-arm#allocation-method).

> Static addresses are only released if a network interface is deleted.
>   If you change the allocation method to dynamic, Azure dynamically
>   assigns the previously assigned static IP address as the dynamic
>   address, even if the address isn't the next available address in the
>   subnet's address range. The address also changes if the network
>   interface is assigned to a different subnet within the same virtual
>   network, but to assign the network interface to a different subnet,
>   you must first change the allocation method from static to dynamic.
>   Once you've assigned the network interface to a different subnet, you
>   can change the allocation method back to static, and assign an IP
>   address from the new subnet's address range.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the setting to static ip in the load balancer , it should remain static until you change it again.